# Best way to check if an absolute uri contains a given relative uri

Tags: c#, uri

Is there a simple way to test if a relative uri happens to exist within a give absolute uri?

For example, this would return true:

Absolute uri: http://www.google.com/path1/path2/blah.html

RelativeUri: ./path2/blah.html

The only way I can think of is to do it directly with string manipulation, but would like to know if there is a direct way to do it using the Uri class.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you concerned about different encodings of value in the querystring (e.g. should `+` and `%20` match)?

Comment: to test whether or not an httpresponse returns a uri that I intend it to return.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so after looking at the documentation, even the URI.Compare() method would require overhead to find the right index making it cost more than String.Contains():
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.compare?view=netframework-4.7.2

Looks like

```
string relURI = @"./path2/blah.html";
bool containsURI = myUri.AbsolutePath.Contains(relURI);
```

might be your best bet (as you implied).

Comment: the only thing with this method is that it isnt complete. For example, in a situation where rel uri is precedes with period, it will always return false, since there should be no period in an absolute uri. Easily resolvable, but I am not sure if there are other caveats